# Julia: Variable not defined

Tags: variables, global-variables, julia

The variable scope behavior seems quite strange. The code block

```
tp = 1
function test2()
    println(tp)
end
```

works perfectly well while

```
function test()
    if tp==0
       tp=tp-1
    end
end
```

gives the exception "tp not defined". What is wrong?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is tricky due to the way variables are implicitly defined as local or global, and the fact that definitions *later* in a function can affect their scoping in the whole function.

In the first case, `tp` defaults to being a global variable, and it works as you expected.  However, in the second case, you *assign* to `tp`.  This, as is noted in the [scope of variables section](http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/variables-and-scoping/) of the manual:

> "An assignment `x = y`  introduces a new local variable `x` only if `x` is neither declared global nor introduced as local by any enclosing scope before or *after* the current line of code."

So, by assigning to `tp`, you've implicitly declared it as a local variable! It will now shadow the definition of your global… except that you try to access it first. The solution is simple: explicitly declare any variables to be global if you want to assign to them:

```
   function test()
       global tp
       if tp==0
          tp=tp-1
       end
   end
```

The behavior here is finely nuanced, but it's very consistent.  I know it took me a few reads through that part of the manual before I finally understood how this works.  If you can think of a better way to describe it, please say something!

Comment: A similar situation appeared in a colleague's code today - this can get very tricky - I think at least the error message has to be change in this case (something like "variable used before defined"), I couldn't see where it's clarified in the docs (an 'anywhere used' local variable overriding reading a global var even beforehand)