# Global variable not defined in Julia

Tags: julia

A similar question has been previously asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24830074/julia-variable-not-defined), but according to the answer to that question and the Julia manual, the following .jl script should work.

```
global myVar = spzeros(10,1);
myVar[3] = 1;

function test_base()
  test1();
end

function test1()
  myVar = [ i > 0 ? 2 : 0 for i in myVar] #doesn't work
end
```

I explicitly declare a variable global and then try to modify it inside a function. However when I attempt to run the function test1(), it says that the variable is undefined.

```
julia> VERSION
v"0.3.5"

julia> include("test.jl")
test1 (generic function with 1 method)

julia> test_base()
ERROR: myVar not defined
 in test1 at /home/clifton/Julia/ca-1/test.jl:9
 in test_base at /home/clifton/Julia/ca-1/test.jl:5
```

I've tried different things, and it does work if I just access the variable in test1(), like `print(myVar);` Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you need to put `global` inside the function that needs to access the global variable.

The following works for me:

```
myVar = spzeros(10,1);
myVar[3] = 1;

function test_base()
    test1();
end

function test1()
    global myVar
    myVar = [ i > 0 ? 2 : 0 for i in myVar] #doesn't work
end
```

Output:

```
julia> include("test.jl")
test1 (generic function with 1 method)

julia> test_base()
10-element Array{Int64,1}:
 0
 0
 2
 0
 0
 0
 0
 0
 0
 0
```