# Julia: Create DataFrame column from expression?

Tags: julia, dataframesmeta.jl

Given this:

```
dict = Dict(("y" => ":x / 2"))

df = DataFrame(x = [1, 2, 3, 4])

df
4×1 DataFrame
│ Row │ x     │
│     │ Int64 │
├─────┼───────┤
│ 1   │ 1     │
│ 2   │ 2     │
│ 3   │ 3     │
│ 4   │ 4     │
```

I want to make this:

```
4×2 DataFrame
│ Row │ x     │ y       │
│     │ Int64 │ Float64 │
├─────┼───────┼─────────┤
│ 1   │ 1     │ 0.5     │
│ 2   │ 2     │ 1.0     │
│ 3   │ 3     │ 1.5     │
│ 4   │ 4     │ 2.0     │
```

This seems like a perfect application for `DataFramesMeta`, either `@with` or `@eachrow`, but I haven't been able to get my expression to evaluate as expected in an environment where `:x` exists.

Basically, I want to be able to iterate over `(k, v)` pairs in `dict` and create one new column for each `Symbol(k)` with corresponding values `eval(Meta.parse(v))`, or something along those lines, where the evaluation occurs such that `Symbols` like `:x` exist at the time of evaluation.

I didn't expect this to work, and it doesn't:

```
[df[Symbol(k)] = eval(Meta.parse(v)) for (k, v) in dict]

ERROR: MethodError: no method matching /(::Symbol, ::Int64)
```

But this illustrates the problem: I need the expressions to be evaluated in an environment where the symbols they contain exist.

However, moving it inside a `@with` doesn't work:

```
using DataFramesMeta

@with(df, [eval(Meta.parse(v)) for (k, v) in dict])

ERROR: MethodError: no method matching /(::Symbol, ::Int64)
```

Using `@eachrow` fails the same way:

```
using DataFramesMeta

@eachrow df begin
           for (k, v) in dict
               @newcol tmp::Vector{Float32}
               tmp = eval(Meta.parse(v))
           end
       end

ERROR: MethodError: no method matching /(::Symbol, ::Int64)
```

I'm guessing I'm unclear on some key element of how `DataFramesMeta` creates an environment within a DataFrame. I also don't necessarily have to use `DataFramesMeta` for this, any reasonably concise option will work since I can encapsulate it in a package function.

Note: I control the format of the strings to be parsed into expressions, but I want to avoid complexity such as specifying the name of the DataFrame object in the string, or broadcasting every operation. I want the expression syntax in the initial string to be reasonably clear to non-Julia programmers.

**UPDATE:** I tried all three solutions in the comments on this question, and they have a problem: they don't work inside functions.

```
dict = Dict(("y" => ":x / 2"))

data = DataFrame(x = [1, 2, 3, 4])


function transform_from_dict(df, dict)

    new = eval(Meta.parse("@transform(df, " * join(join.(collect(dict), " = "), ", ") * ")"))

    return new

end

transform_from_dict(data, dict)

ERROR: UndefVarError: df not defined
```

Or:

```
function transform_from_dict!(df, dict)

    [df[!, Symbol(k)] = eval(:(@with(df, $(Meta.parse(v))))) for (k, v) in dict]

    return nothing

end

transform_from_dict!(data, dict)

ERROR: UndefVarError: df not defined
```

Comment: try `[df[!,Symbol(k)] = eval(DataFramesMeta.with_helper(df, Meta.parse(v))) for (k, v) in dict]`

Comment: or `[df[!,Symbol(k)] = eval(:(@with(df, $(Meta.parse(v))))) for (k, v) in dict]`. Both are tricky though. The key is you do not want to directly `eval` `v`, instead, let `DataFramesMeta` to eval it with its magic.

Comment: In general I would not recommend doing such operations as they are unsafe. If you really need to do this then e.g. this will work `eval(Meta.parse("@transform(df, " * join(join.(collect(dict), " = "), ", ") * ")"))`.

Comment: Thanks for these! For people who come across this question, I agree that it's an insecure design pattern and should generally be avoided.

Comment: @BogumiłKamiński @张实唯 FYI, after testing all three solutions in my REPL (which worked perfectly), I noticed that all three fail in the same way when moved inside a function. I've updated the question with examples of that. I think it's again related to the magic of how `DataFramesMeta` creates its `eval` environment.

Comment: they will fail inside a function because `eval` is evaluated in global scope of the module. DataFramesMeta.jl does not create `eval` environment, but its macros are resolved at compile time not at run time.

Comment: Aha. That was the piece I was missing. I wonder if there's a way to do this, or something like it, at all. Essentially, I'd like a user to be able to define a set of transformations that will be applied to some data.

Comment: Add `global new` at the start of your script and add `global new` as well at the start of the the function (*inside* the function). This is a general trick in Pyton and works with any object that needs to be read at run-time and still grow over time. See https://thispointer.com/python-how-to-use-global-variables-in-a-function/. Perhaps it also works in julia. Then the df can grow over any list / dict comprehension. Untested: perhaps it also works in combination with eval() + Meta.parse(). And by the way: I had not seen that his was julia and not Python, please transfer the idea to julia.

Comment: The question is tagged Julia, but I edited the title to clarify.

Comment: Anyway, the trick will be the same in julia, Python, or whatever language. You simply need to add `global new` *inside* the function, at its start. See this [julia link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/julia-global-keyword-creating-a-global-variable-in-julia) about how to use global variables inside of a function. If that does not work, also add `global new` outside of the function at the start of the script, since that is definitely needed in Python, though it seems that julia does not need this when looking at the example in the link.

Comment: I tried adding `global new` in the main script and / or in the function, but I always got errors. It seems as if the `global` trick does not work with eval(). There is still a chance that my testing was wrong. I have checked this in an online compiler, and strangely, [this surely working examle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28424470/global-variable-not-defined-in-julia) is using exactly the trick that is meant but did not show any output in my online compiler. That means: give it a try! :)

Comment: That does in fact work! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have worked on this answer in parallel to @Ajar, nothing is copied from that answer nor did I know about it. I was totally new to Julia so I had to install it (because I thought the online compilers did not even know a DataFrame), later I understood that these packages must be called at start anyway, be it online or offline. I have added the package information that beginners might need to know.

```
using Pkg 
Pkg.add("DataFrames")
Pkg.add("DataFramesMeta")

using DataFrames
using DataFramesMeta 
dict = Dict(("y" => ":x / 2"))
df = DataFrame(x = [1, 2, 3, 4])
```

**The @with solution:**

```
julia> function transform_from_dict!(k, v)
           global df
           df[!, Symbol(k)] = eval(:(@with(df, $(Meta.parse(v)))))
           return nothing
       end
```

> ```
> transform_from_dict! (generic function with 2 methods)
> ```

```
julia> [transform_from_dict!(k, v) for (k, v) in dict]
```

> ```
> 1-element Array{Nothing,1}:
>  nothing
> ```

```
julia> df
```

> ```
> 4×2 DataFrame
>  Row │ x      y
>      │ Int64  Float64
> ─────┼────────────────
>    1 │     1      0.5
>    2 │     2      1.0
>    3 │     3      1.5
>    4 │     4      2.0
> ```

**The @transform solution:**

```
julia> function transform_from_dict(df, dict)
           global new
           new = eval(Meta.parse("@transform(df, " * join(join.(collect(dict), " = "), ", ") * ")"))

           return new

       end
```

> ```
> transform_from_dict (generic function with 1 method)
> ```

```
julia>

julia> transform_from_dict(data, dict)
4×2 DataFrame
 Row │ x      y
     │ Int64  Float64
─────┼────────────────
   1 │     1      0.5
   2 │     2      1.0
   3 │     3      1.5
   4 │     4      2.0
```

Thanks go to the other commentators, the essential ideas listed in @Ajar's answer.

Answer (score 1):

OK, combining answers from all of the commenters works!

```
using DataFrames
using DataFramesMeta

dict = Dict(("y" => ":x / 2"))

data = DataFrame(x = [1, 2, 3, 4])
```

[@张实唯](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4411558/%E5%BC%A0%E5%AE%9E%E5%94%AF)'s approach using `@with`:

```
# using @with
function transform_from_dict1(df, dict)

    global df

    [df[!, Symbol(k)] = eval(:(@with(df, $(Meta.parse(v))))) for (k, v) in dict]

    return df

end

transform_from_dict1(data, dict)
# 4×2 DataFrame
# │ Row │ x     │ y       │
# │     │ Int64 │ Float64 │
# ├─────┼───────┼─────────┤
# │ 1   │ 1     │ 0.5     │
# │ 2   │ 2     │ 1.0     │
# │ 3   │ 3     │ 1.5     │
# │ 4   │ 4     │ 2.0     │
```

And [@Bogumił Kamiński](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1269567/bogumi%C5%82-kami%C5%84ski)'s approach using `@transform`:

```
# using @transform
function transform_from_dict2(df, dict)

    global df

    new_df = eval(Meta.parse("@transform(df, " * join(join.(collect(dict), " = "), ", ") * ")"))

    return new_df

end

transform_from_dict2(data, dict)
# 4×2 DataFrame
# │ Row │ x     │ y       │
# │     │ Int64 │ Float64 │
# ├─────┼───────┼─────────┤
# │ 1   │ 1     │ 0.5     │
# │ 2   │ 2     │ 1.0     │
# │ 3   │ 3     │ 1.5     │
# │ 4   │ 4     │ 2.0     │
```

Both incorporate the fix from [@Lorenz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11154841/lorenz) using `global`.

Note that the second form uses about 2.5x more memory than the first, likely due to the creation of a second `DataFrame`:

```
julia> @allocated transform_from_dict1(data, dict)
853948

julia> @allocated transform_from_dict2(data, dict)
22009111
```

I also think the first form is a little more clear, so that's what I'm using internally.

Note that you may need to broadcast logical operators if you have those in your transforms, and that as usual you'll need to handle any missing data issues up front.

Comment: So fair of you to accept my answer. Thank you, and you get a definite upvote as well, because you could not expect me to answer as I was totally new to Julia. Thank you for the fair game. Another upvote for the time test.